# Computing relative homography from bundle adjustment

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

I have a set of aerial images and I run them through Bundler (SfM) which gives me the rotation and translation matrices of all cameras relative to a random coordinate system.

I want to take two of those images, `img0` and `img1`. The first one I assume is aligned with a reference frame and therefore `H0 = eye(3)`. I want to compute `H1`, the Homography from `img1` to `img0` so that I can stitch them into a photo-mosaic,

`warpPerspective(img1, img1_warped, H1)`

I think this `H1`, accounting rotation and translation, should be given by

`H1 = K1*R1*(eye(3) + ((t1 - t0)*n.t() / t0.z))*R0.t()*K0.inv()`

eye(3) is the identity matrix, .t() is the transpose operator and .inv() the inverse matrix.

However this is not working very well. What am I missing?

Comment: did you finally find a way to do this ? please share if you did. i'm facing a similar problem.

Comment: @ArjunJRao Hmography does not apply in this case. It's not a good approach as this does not use the planar assumption homography does.

Comment: then what did you use to perform the mosaicing ?

Comment: @ArjunJRao pure homography! checkout CloudCompare